# PHPUnit install

Tags: php, phpunit, wamp

I have install PHPUnit using pear but when I try to make a test I get the following error on including the phpunit framework.

this is the php test script

```
<?php
require_once ('PHPUnit/Framework');

class Mytest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $o;
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->o=new Myclass();
    }
    public function testId()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(null,$this->o->getID());
    }
}

class Myclass{
    private $_id;
    public function getID()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

End the erro is code is:

```
require_once(C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\pear\PHPUnit\Framework): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I tried a lot of things but couldn't get no result!!

Comment: Did u chmod the directory 755 and the files 644?

Comment: You're missing `.php` at the end of the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `require` function in PHP includes files in the current file. This is different from the `require` function that your properbly are used to use in Ruby, where it means 'load a library'.

But you can remove the complete require function from this case. If you test the complete test suite (with `phpunit`) the PHPunit classes will automatically included, so you can use them directly.

Answer (score 2):

require once expects a file. Most likely the change required is to replace:

```
require_once ('PHPUnit/Framework');
```

with:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';
```

note that [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) is a statement, not a function - the parentheses serve no purpose.